# VS Code is replacing text

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to type `console.log`, the moment I press the full stop, VS Code replaces that text with `crossOriginIsolated`. The only way for me to actually type `console.log` is to type `.log` then type `console` in front of it. I like having the suggestions but when I press full stop it just replaces whatever text I'm trying to type.

Comment: See what plugins you have installed. This sound kind of a plugins settings. If you did not find the plugins try reinstalling VS Code, it should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to try reinstalling as I have no plugins just a fresh install.

Comment: see answer below, this is not caused by a plugin, it is a default behavior of vscode when you accidentally type 'consold' instead of 'console'

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your 'settings.json' file :

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
```

To open the 'settings.json' file:

1. cmd + , or ctrl + ,
2. List item
3. scroll down until you see 'Files: Associations'
4. Click on 'edit in settings.json' paste the code above and save.

Besides that, you can type `log` and press Enter. It will autocomplete `console.log`

Comment: no need to scroll - type `commit`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you make a very specific typo while attempting to write `console.log`. Specifically, if you type **consold** or **consolt**. The <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd> keys are both near the <kbd>E</kbd> key, so it's a plausible mistake to make.

The reason this occurs is that, when you type a non-existent symbol in vscode, it will attempt to auto-correct it by matching your with a real symbol that has all of those letters in that same order. This is a helpful rule often, especially for correcting missing-letter typos. For instance, "cosole" would autocorrect to "console" using this rule. There is exactly one valid JS symbol which has the letters c-o-n-s-o-l-d in that order and it's **c**r**o**ssOrigi**n**I**sol**ate**d**:

[image]

There is unfortunately no way to disable just this one autocorrect suggestion by itself, but if you really feel you can't tolerate it, there is a more targeted solution than disabling autocorrect entirely. You can suppress this behavior by disabling autocorrect for variables only:

[image]

In my opinion, losing variable autocorrect is too great a price to pay to correct this behavior, so personally I've decided to just live with it.